# Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, sendmail

I am trying to send mail using Microsoft graph API's but stucked at the below error when calling the send mail API at - graphClient.Users["UserID"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody)

"Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed"

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "XXX";
var clientId = "XXX";
var clientSecret = "XXX";
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "xxx@xxx.com",
                },
            },
        },
        CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "xxx@xxx.com",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    SaveToSentItems = false,
};

await graphClient.Users["UserID"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Cross checked with delegated and Application permissions in Microsoft documentation and granted all of them but no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried almsot all methods but it turns out it somehow related to your accoutn status as per : [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1195189/using-application-permission-on-personal-microsoft?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1195633#newest-answer-comment)

Personal accounts cannot use application permissions which is what caused it for me.

Answer (score 0):

That error means your getting a html response to the REST request which even in error (eg permission etc) it should always be a JSON response. There could be a number of reason for this one common one is a proxy server is responding with a authentication form.

What you could do is use something like fiddler to look at traffic and the actual response. Also the Graph proxy https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/introducing-the-microsoft-graph-developer-proxy-community-preview/ can allow you to see the Graph requests and responses.

You should also check the permissions/roles in your token using jwt.io to ensure your getting all the permissions you need. You can get access to token in a debugger using

```
 var tokenResult = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }));
```

I would also try to access that mailbox using the Graph Explorer it could also be something at the Mailbox access level.