# Using Azure MS Graph API Service Account with Managed Identity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have got my Azure Portal setup with an app registration and the associated managed identity for my web api as well. As confusing as it seemed I was able to deploy my app and I tested out a basic command to pull the list of users in my azure tenant as shown below with the commented out code. I am using a service account for everything but I wanted to pull the calendar for a specific user and see their data and it came back with the following error:

> "Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be
> parsed"

I then tried it for pulling that users email messages and got the same error when trying to return the result. My permissions in the enterprise application are as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetCalendar")]
[OktaAuthorizeAttribute]
[EnableRateLimiting("api")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var credential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
        new ManagedIdentityCredential(),
        new EnvironmentCredential());

    string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        credential, scopes);
    List<MSGraphUser> msGraphUsers = new List<MSGraphUser>();

    try
    {
        //var result = await graphServiceClient.Users["dfasdfdfdsafklsaf-dfsdaf-sdfdf-d"].Events.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        //{
        //    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "subject", "body", "bodyPreview", "organizer", "attendees", "start", "end", "location" };
        //});

        var result = await graphServiceClient.Users["dfasdfdfdsafklsaf-dfsdaf-sdfdf-d"].Messages.GetAsync();
        //var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
        return Ok(msg);
    }
}
```

Am I using the service account incorrectly in general or in my code? I know to do things on behalf of the user I would authorization flow and I am using client credential flow but when I look at the descriptions of these permissions I set (ie calendar.readwrite : Allows the app to create, read, update, and delete events of all calendars without a signed-in user.) it makes me think I should have access to ALL users so even the ones below.

I was thinking it could be using the Users[""] , i tried the email address and also the id from the user query I was able to pull originally since it gives it and nothing.

Comment: Well done for posting the error. You have no idea how many people don't even make it that far. The error doesn't look like an authorisation issue, it just looks like the returned payload is of type `text/html` but you don't have a library to parse it. If you could actually view whatever is returned you'll probably find it's an error message written in HTML https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230530/content-type-text-html-does-not-have-a-factory-registered-to-be-parsed

Comment: I need to figure out how to locally debug this in visual studio. I setup managed identity and it’s like I didn’t have to add anything to my program.cs. However for debugging purposes I do keep my client if, tenant, and secret in a user secret. How would I  change my var credential to not use managed identity and manually use my tenant id, , clientid, and secret?

Comment: Also do I need to manually assign users to the app itself? I just assumed the global admins (my username by default when creating azure portal account) is assigned since it shows up in the user api request I have in my commented code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I agree with @***Nick.McDermaid***, it is not an authorization issue.

I created an Azure Web App and turned-on Identity like below:

[image]

Now, I assigned **permissions to the Enterprise application** like below:

[image]

Generated the **access token** via Kudu like below:

```java
$resourceURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=2019-08-01"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"X-IDENTITY-HEADER"="$env:IDENTITY_HEADER"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
```

[image]

Check if the **access token has proper permissions** by decoding the token:

[image]

I tried to retrieve user by using the above access token successfully:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID
```

[image]

The error "***Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed***" usually occurs if the response is not in the expected format that is the response must be in JSON format.

The error might occur due to several reasons like:

- The proxy server between web app and the Microsoft Graph API is returning an HTML response.
- The Microsoft Graph API is returning an HTML response due to an issue with the code.
- The response content type might have not set to `application/json`.

**To resolve the error**, Install Fiddler and check the HTTP traffic between web application and the Microsoft Graph API.

You can also make use of [**Microsoft Graph Developer Proxy**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/introducing-the-microsoft-graph-developer-proxy-community-preview/) by *Sébastien Levert* to check the Microsoft Graph request details.

- Use the generated access token and in the Microsoft Graph API to check if the request works.
- Try making use of `newtonsoft.json` library and check.

**If still the issue persists** after the above changes, then make use of Authorization code flow and check.

**UPDATE:**

To resolve the issue, upgrade to a business package, assign the user to license and then set up.

**Reference:**

[azure - Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230530/content-type-text-html-does-not-have-a-factory-registered-to-be-parsed) by Glen Scales.

Comment: Can you try the calendar or message endpoint like my code which produces the error? The user endpoint worked for me as well. Also I’ll checkout fiddler as I’ve never used it. One thing that might help for me is I am not sure how I can do local development if I am using managed identities since they require it being uploaded to app services first. So I am unable to local debug which would be great. I locally store the tenant Id, client secret, etc of my app registration in user secrets to grab my key vaults but I’m not sure how to change my code above to use those credentials for ms graph v5.

Comment: Hey SO I have read in a few areas that maybe service accounts/application permissions are not usable on personal azure accounts. Could this be my issue? Maybe I should just upgrade to a business package to see if it fixes it?

Comment: Yeah sure please check by upgrading the package.

Comment: Any chance you know the minimum/cheapest package that would accomplish allowing this? MS has made it pretty confusing. I see there is aad premium1 and premium 2 but not sure which is required. Or can I just get any MS business account like their basic plan (ie, anything that is not a personal/free account).

Comment: Or if not what are you using? AD Premium 1 or 2?

Comment: My issue was that I need needed to upgrade to a business package, assign the user to that license, and open one drive or whatever service once to set it up. Add this to your solution and I will accept it. You have all the correct steps for me to debug mine. I used postman instead though to prove my access token had the scopes assigned to the default auth server and it did which made me realize it had to be the business package.

Comment: Thank you again for your help and taking the time to do your answer. Got me in the right direction and helped me learn the individual steps the sdk does to make this all work.