# Microsoft Graph throwing "Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed"

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm walking through a console app tutorial from Microsoft to deal with outlook mail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=5)

I did everything as is, but when I try to test it I get this exception when the GET request is sent.

> Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed.

The code:

```
public static Task<MessageCollectionResponse?> GetInboxAsync()
{
    // Ensure client isn't null
    _ = _userClient ??
        throw new System.NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for user auth");

    return _userClient.Me
        // Only messages from Inbox folder
        .MailFolders["Inbox"]
        .Messages
        .GetAsync((config) =>
        {
            //The next two lines were added by me to try to fix the problem
            config.Headers.Clear();
            config.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            // Only request specific properties
            config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "from", "isRead", "receivedDateTime", "subject" };
            // Get at most 25 results
            config.QueryParameters.Top = 25;
            // Sort by received time, newest first
            config.QueryParameters.Orderby = new[] { "receivedDateTime DESC" };
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you use delegated or application permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I followed same [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=1) and registered one Azure AD application with **Supported account type** as below and enabled public client flows:

[image]

I have one tenant named **DemoAAD** having `Azure AD Free` license like below:

[image]

In my case, I got **same error** when I ran same code by signing in with user from above tenant:

```
dotnet run
2
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, update your Azure AD license to **`Premium`**
> and make sure to assign **Office 365 license** to your user account.

I have another tenant with **`Azure AD Premium P2`** license like below:

[image]

In above tenant, I assigned an active **Office 365 license** to one user account:

[image]

When I ran same code, I picked user account having active **Office 365 license** from `Azure AD Premium P2` licensed tenant to login where I got consent prompt like this:

[image]

After accepting the consent, I entered `2` and got **list of inbox messages** successfully in console output like below:

```
dotnet run
2
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[c# - Using Azure MS Graph API Service Account  - Stack Overflow by **Rukmini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76511237/using-azure-ms-graph-api-service-account-with-managed-identity/76512391#76512391)

Answer (score 0):

this error `Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed` means you got an html content as the response which always indicating the request got error.

My suggestion to narrow down the issue is:

```
public static Task<MessageCollectionResponse?> GetInboxAsync()
{
    // Ensure client isn't null
    _ = _userClient ??
        throw new System.NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for user auth");

    var a = await _userClient.Me.GetAsync();//test if graph Client is set correctly
    //checking if permission is enough to query messages and if the user account have Email account binding to user account
    var b = await _userClient.Me.Messages.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "sender","subject" };
            });
    //add break point here to see the error message.
    var res = await _userClient.Me
        .MailFolders["Inbox"]
        .Messages
        .GetAsync((config) =>
        {
            //The next two lines were added by me to try to fix the problem
            //config.Headers.Clear();
            //config.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            // Only request specific properties
            config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "from", "isRead", "receivedDateTime", "subject" };
            // Get at most 25 results
            //config.QueryParameters.Top = 25;
            config.QueryParameters.Orderby = new[] { "receivedDateTime DESC" };
        });
    return res;
}
```